# What is the best way of adjusting the edge of this shape so that it won't cutt off my leaf texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, edit-mode, extrude

Beginner question I know :), but I really can't figure out how to reshape the leaf without it just stretching the current texture. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: 2 ways, shape it and then unwrap your UV again, second option would be to use double G button to slide those vertices in place (this way your UV won't deform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the shape of the mesh itself without deforming its texture, in that case enable the option called *Correct Face Attributes* in the *Options* panel on the top right of your 3D view:

[image]

[image]