# Extrude Edge Messes up My Texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, edges, extrude

I want the corner of my leaf pixels to be visible, but when I try and extrude the edge of an existing face (with correct face attributes turned on too) I get this weird glitch instead. How can I get the rest of my leaf to work?
[image]

Comment: hello, is it not working this way? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242441/what-is-the-best-way-of-adjusting-the-edge-of-this-shape-so-that-it-wont-cutt-o/242448#242448

Comment: @moonboots It was kind of working but kept warping the texture. Here's what I mean
https://imgur.com/acoKMiS
I appreciate you going out of your way man :)

Comment: @moonboots Finally got the hang of it!!! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, actually, not a glitch.

When you extrude an edge, a vertex or a face; Blender 'copies' the UV coordinates of the extruded part to the new part so, in your case, the new edge that you created has the same UV coordinates as the one you extruded it from, hence the weird result you see here.

Let me explain :

In this simple scene, I have a plane with a texture but the texture is not applied well :

[image: What it looks like in the 3D view]

The reason for this can be seen from the **UV/image editor** :

[image]

If you try to correct that problem by extruding, you will have this :

[image]

And in the UV editor you will see that **nothing** seems to have changed since you can't see the new edge you created (note that the UV editor shows only vertices/edges/faces that are selected in the viewport so you may need to press **A** in the 3D viewport to select all your geometry in order to make them appear in the UV editor) :

[image]

The reason for that is that, the corresponding UV of the newly created edge is at the same location as the first one, if I select the top two vertices in the UV editor and move them around you can see that the other two were hidden underneath them :

[image]
[image]

So you could try to solve your problem by moving the vertices manually in the UV editor :

[image]

And this would somewhat solve your problem but it's not the most efficient way to do it.

Instead, it would be better to not extrude any geometry and just re-unwrap the whole mesh. Since your mesh is not very complicated, it should be simple enough :

[image]

In my case I just pressed **A** to select all (in the 3D view) and pressed **U** and then `unwrap`. This should work perfectly if you mesh is just a flat leaf card.